# Multiple Key KeyStroke for Menu Shortcuts in Java

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application

I am working on a program that maintains data for multiple different purposes, such as loads, vehicle service, brokers, customers, fuel purchases, as well as other types of purchases.

To this end, I have used a `JMenu` to contain the menu items for creating these new data items. So, the user can press, for example, `ALT+N, L` to open the new load wizard. This is just simple menu navigation.

Is there also a way to create a keyboard shortcut, such as `CTLR+N, L` that would do basically the same thing, but without opening the menus?

What I mean is, the user presses `CTLR+N` and the system waits for another key, which would be `L` for new loads, `B` for new broker entry, etc. I was using some program (I can't remember which program off-hand) that had functionality like this. I don't know what language it was written in, but I remember thinking that it was cool that the developers had created multiple hot keys based off of standard keyboard shortcuts by simply waiting for a third key to be pressed separately from the `CTRL+${KEY}` combination.

I have been searching online for an idea of how to accomplish this feat, but am not seeing anything close to what I am looking for. Just to be clear about what I am trying to do, look at the following:

- I have a module for handling the load tracking data, which comes with a wizard for entering new loads. To launch this wizard, I would like the keyboard shortcut to be displayed on the New...Load Wizard menu item as `CTRL+N, L`. When the user presses `CTRL+N` the application waits to see what key is pressed next. If the next key pressed is `N`, then the New Load Wizard is launched.
- I have a module for handling the broker data, which has a data entry dialog for entering new brokers. To open this dialog, I would like the keyboard shortcut to be displayed on the New...Broker menu item as `CTRL+N, B`. When the user presses `CTRL+N` the application waits to see what key is pressed next. If the next key pressed is `B`, then the New Broker dialog is displayed.
- I have a module for handling vehicle services, maintenance, and repairs, which has a single dialog for entering the information regarding these purchases. I would like the keyboard shortcut to be displayed on the New...Service/Repair menu item as `CTRL+N, S`. When the user presses `CTRL+N` the application waits to see what key is pressed next. If the next key pressed is `S`, then the New Service/Repair dialog is opened.
- There will be a similar menu item under the New menu for the other modules in the application, which should function the same way.
- If the key pressed after the `CTRL+N` KeyStroke is not one of the available single shortcut keys displayed on the various New menu items, then it cancels the wait for the next key press. In other words, if the user presses `CTRL+N`, then presses, for example, `Z` (which has no menu item associated with it) the `CTRL+N` is simply discarded.

I am not sure if I have explained what I am trying to do clearly enough, so am more than willing to answer questions to allow for better understanding of my thoughts. Even so, any ideas or thoughts are greatly appreciated!

-SC

Comment: I too have seen applications do this.  It is possible to do in Java, though there is no way to make a JMenuItem display such a “compound” accelerator, as the text is always generated directly from a JMenuItem’s accelerator property which is a single KeyStroke value.  However, this practice is less than ideal in terms of user experience;  I have never seen an application that provided a visual indication of being in “partial accelerator” mode, so users can’t tell when they’ve typed the Ctrl-N part and the application is waiting for the remaining keys.

Comment: @VGR: I was thinking the same thing regarding the "partial accelerator mode"...I am thinking something along the lines of placing a message on the status bar that says something like, "NEW ITEM: waiting for command key. One of L(oad), B(roker), C(ustomer), P(urchase), S(ervice), or F(uel)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it.

I set a flag after the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and then if the user presses <kbd>b</kbd>, perform the appropriate action if the flag is set.

The below code is simply a [proof of concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept) (POC).

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class BindKeys {
    private boolean  flag;
    private JTextField  textField;

    private JPanel createButton() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Exit");
        button.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));
        panel.add(button);
        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createTextField() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        textField = new JTextField(12);
        InputMap im = textField.getInputMap();
        KeyStroke ctrlN = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        im.put(ctrlN, "SET_FLAG");
        KeyStroke b = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('b');
        im.put(b, "NEW_BROKER");
        ActionMap am = textField.getActionMap();
        am.put("SET_FLAG", new CtrlNAction());
        am.put("NEW_BROKER", new BAction());
        
        panel.add(textField);
        return panel;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createTextField(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createButton(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class BAction extends AbstractAction {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (flag) {
                textField.setText("New broker");
            }
            else {
                textField.setText(textField.getText() + "b");
            }
        }
    }

    private class CtrlNAction extends AbstractAction {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new BindKeys().showGui());
    }
}
```

Refer to [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: +1 @Abra: Thank you! This PoC works like a champ. I appreciate the effort you made and it is cleaner than anything that I have tried, such as the `CTRL+N` starting a thread that waits for another key to be pressed. This method uses less resources as well. I am marking this as answered.